# AngularJS & Laravel: Upload file & grab on server

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm using the [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) directive, to upload a file to my server, via a POST request, however I'm getting confused.

I have my input box setup: `<input type="file" ng-model="image['file']" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($file)" >`

I assign the file to the `$scope.upload` on select:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($file) {

    $scope.upload = $file;
};
```

Now, when I press my "upload" button I want to send some data (`$scope.image`) to the server, but also my uploaded file so I can get it validated.

I created a `Collection` service for this, as follows:

```
    ...
    validateUpload : function( data, upload ) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/url/to/upload',
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
            data: data,
            file: upload
        });
    },
    ...
```

Okay, so now in my controller I can try to upload the data:

```
Collection.validateUpload( $scope.image, $scope.upload )
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

In my Laravel Controller, I can access the `$scope.image` data quite easily:

```
return Input::all();

= Object {file: "C:\fakepath\myimage.png", title: "Title", source: "A Source"}
```

However, I wish to access my file. According to the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files) I should be able to access this with:

```
Input::file('file');
```

However, it doesn't seem to be grabbing anything at all. For example, running `->getSize()` on this complains about trying to access something which isn't an object.

Anyone got any idea how I get that file?

EDIT: Seems after a bit more playing, when I `console.log($file);` when selected, its `undefined`, hm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($file) {
    $scope.upload = $file[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i am doing this if it helps

view.blade.php

```
<div ng-controller="fupController">

        <input type="file" id="file1" name="file" multiple
            ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />

        <input type="button" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
    </div>
```

angular controller

```
app.directive('ngFiles', ['$parse', function ($parse) {

        function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChange = $parse(attrs.ngFiles);
            element.on('change', function (event) {
                onChange(scope, { $files: event.target.files });
            });
        };

        return {
            link: fn_link
        }
    } ]);

    app.controller('fupController', function ($scope, $http , API_URL) {

        var formdata = new FormData();
        $scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
            angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
                formdata.append(key, value);
            });
        };

        //alert(formdata);

        // NOW UPLOAD THE FILES.
        $scope.uploadFiles = function () {

            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: API_URL + 'uploadEntry',
                data: formdata,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                }
            };

            // SEND THE FILES.
            $http(request)
                .success(function (d) {
                    //alert(d);
                })
                .error(function () {
                });
        }
    });
```

API Route for laravel 5.3

```
Route::post('fileupload', 'userController@fileupload');
```

controller

```
public function uploadEntry(Request $request){
      //laravel form submission
      /*  
      if($request->hasFile('uploadedFile')){
        $files = $request->file('uploadedFile');
        foreach ($files as $file) {  
            $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.jpg';
            $file->move( 'uploads' , $fileName);
        }
      } */

      //angular API submission

        $file = 0; 
        while (Input::file($file)->isValid()) {
          $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
          $fileName =  rand(11111,99999).'.jpg'; // renameing image
          Input::file($file)->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
          $file++;
        }
   }
```

follow this to upload multiple images